# Correct PEM format for a file in AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, pem

I am trying to upload a secret in AWS Secrets Manager. The file is in the format

```
{
 "privateKeyPassword": "testpassword",
 "certificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE5DCCAsygAwIBAgIRAPJdwaFaNRrytHBto0j5BA0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
...
j0Lh4/+1HfgyE2KlmII36dg4IMzNjAFEBZiCRoPimO40s1cRqtFHXoal0QQbIlxk
cmUuiAii9R0=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFgjCCA2qgAwIBAgIQdjNZd6uFf9hbNC5RdfmHrzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBb
...
rQoiowbbk5wXCheYSANQIfTZ6weQTgiCHCCbuuMKNVS95FkXm0vqVD/YpXKwA/no
c8PH3PSoAaRwMMgOSA2ALJvbRz8mpg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----",
 "privateKey": "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIFKzBVBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wSDAnBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwGgQUiAFcK5hT/X7Kjmgp
...
QrSekqF+kWzmB6nAfSzgO9IaoAaytLvNgGTckWeUkWn/V0Ck+LdGUXzAC4RxZnoQ
zp2mwJn2NYB7AZ7+imp0azDZb+8YG2aUCiyqb6PnnA==
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"
}
```

which exactly matches with the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kafka.html#:%7E:text=The%20following%20example%20shows%20the%20contents%20of%20a%20secret%20for%20mTLS%20authentication%20using%20an%20encrypted%20private%20key.%20For%20an%20encrypted%20private%20key%2C%20include%20the%20private%20key%20password%20in%20the%20secret.).
But when I run my lambda function I get an error in the configuration:

```
Last processing result: PROBLEM: Certificate and/or private key must be in PEM format.
```

I think the encrypted key is the problem, I need to add the private key password in the secret. I am not sure how to do that or if this is the problem?
How can I rectify this?

Comment: the `...` in the documentation mean that you should put your own certificate there. It's not a valid format.

Comment: Yes I know, I used it as an example. I wanted to bring to notice that the private key is encrypted, how to work it out?

Answer (score 3):

The correct format is a well-formed JSON and each break line in the PEM values should be replaced by the `\n` character, as follows:

```json
{
  "privateKeyPassword": "testpassword",
  "certificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIE5DCCAsygAwIBAgIRAPJdwaFaNRrytHBto0j5BA0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw\n...\nj0Lh4/+1HfgyE2KlmII36dg4IMzNjAFEBZiCRoPimO40s1cRqtFHXoal0QQbIlxk\ncmUuiAii9R0=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----",
  "privateKey": "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIFKzBVBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wSDAnBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwGgQUiAFcK5hT/X7Kjmgp\n...\nQrSekqF+kWzmB6nAfSzgO9IaoAaytLvNgGTckWeUkWn/V0Ck+LdGUXzAC4RxZnoQ\nzp2mwJn2NYB7AZ7+imp0azDZb+8YG2aUCiyqb6PnnA==\n-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"
}
```

Comment: after you retrieve your key from the JSON, you have to use Regex.Unescape to make use of the key, so that it will be in the proper format.

Answer (score -1):

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-ranger-tls-certificates.html

just paste in the key in the Plaintext tab in AWS Secret Manger.
To retrieve it this will work:

aws secretsmanager get-secret-value  --secret-id secretName  --query 'SecretString'  --output text